# Changing color of fetched amino acids

Tags: biopython, pymol

I want to write a PyMOL script to change a color of an amino acid in the XYZ position (or somehow put some marker with label in the XYZ position).

Does any body know how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to color by position AND residue? So you'd color, say, LEU in one position differently than a LEU in different position?

Comment: I need to write a script to mark (some how) a SNP in amino acids graphic representation in PyMOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you know [pseudoatom](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Pseudoatom) and [label](http://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Label) in PyMOL?

```
# to create a banner at certain position
pseudoatom mypsatm, pos=[10.0,10.0,10.0]  
show spheres, mypsatm
color red, mypsatm                     # now you see me
hide everything, mypsatm
label mypsatm, 'How about this'        # only show banner  

# to select residues close to that position
select mysel, byres mypsatm around 4   # 4 Angstroms around mypsatm
```

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for :). Can I specify amino acid number instead of position ? //add label for 'V' in 'IVGGQ'

Comment: of course you can. If your residue id is 2, then use: **select myres, resi 2**. Do have a look here: http://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Property_Selectors